# Access C variable in swift

Tags: swift, swift3, header, interop, bridge

I'm trying to access a state variable declare in .h file but the compiler said the variable doesn't exist. Do I need to add anything in my bridging header file ?

In my swift file I can't access ***dstate*** or ***cstate***

The compiler says "Use of unresolved identifier 'dstate'" on the line `g722_coder_init(&dstate)`.

[image: Compiler error]

**Header file**

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

extern struct g722_dstate dstate;
extern struct g722_cstate cstate;

int g722_coder_init (  struct g722_cstate *s  );
int g722_encode(short *data, unsigned char *outdata,int len, struct g722_cstate *s  );
int g722_decoder_init (  struct g722_dstate *s);
int  g722_decode(unsigned char *decdata, short *pcmout, int len,  struct g722_dstate *s );

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

**Bridging Header**

```
#import "g722_codec.h"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `struct g722_dstate` is an "incomplete type",
and Swift cannot import variables of an incomplete type, only variables
which are  *pointers* to an incomplete type (and those are imported
as `OpaquePointer`).

Adding the complete struct definition to the imported header file would
be the easiest solution.

If that is not possible then one workaround would be to add

```
#import "g722_codec.h"

static struct g722_dstate * __nonnull dstatePtr = &dstate;
```

to the bridging header file, which defines a variable containing the
address of the "opaque" `dstate` variable. This is imported to Swift as

```
var dstatePtr: OpaquePointer
```

and can then be used e.g. as

```
g722_coder_init(dstatePtr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like create a function in c file and Add function name as forward declaration in bridging header
For example -

```
//In c File you have definition & forward declaration
int g722_encode(short *data, unsigned char *outdata,int len, struct g722_cstate *s  );
int g722_encode(short *data, unsigned char *outdata,int len, struct g722_cstate *s  ){

}
```

Bridging header should be -

```
 #import "g722_codec.h"
int g722_encode(short *data, unsigned char *outdata,int len, struct g722_cstate *s  );
```