# Access to extern C array from Swift

Tags: c, swift

I have a Swift framework that uses a C library imported through a simple modulemap file:

```
module tulip {
  header "indicators.h"
  export *
}
```

Most of the elements defined inside the `indicators.h` header are accessible by importing `import tulip`.

However, one `extern` C array is unaccessible:

```
extern ti_indicator_info ti_indicators[];
```

The generated Swift interface does not contain any reference to `ti_indicators`.

Switching to a pointer declaration instead would work but would require some additionnal changes to the original header or adding some wrapping code.

Is there any particular reason why I would not be able to reference this C array from a Swift code?

Comment: An array without size is an “incomplete type” and therefore not imported into Swift. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/43365067/1187415 for a similar issue.